# Paramiko SSH set environment variable using python

Tags: python, ssh, environment-variables, paramiko

I am using Paramiko to send an ssh command to a remote Windows Server, which works, BUT I need to set an environment variable first which sets a password for the main command to use.
So on the Windows Server command line I use:

```
$ set ASPERA_SCP_PASS=passwordToUse
$ ascp -d --src-base=//DirectoryToSend //DirectoryToSend username@123.23.34.1:/
```

This sets an environment variable `passwordToUse` which gets used in the `ascp` command.
But I can't get this working with Paramiko. When running the below script I get `exit status:  0`, but the command does not run on the remote server.

```
import sys
import paramiko

nbytes = 4096
hostname = '10.0.0.1'
port = 22
username = 'remoteUsername' 
password = 'remotePassword'
command1 = 'set ASPERA_SCP_PASS={}'.format('passwordToUse')
command2 = 'ascp -d --src-base=//DirectoryToSend //DirectoryToSend username@123.23.34.1:/'
command3 = command1 + ", " + command2

client = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
client.connect(username=username, password=password)

stdout_data = []
stderr_data = []
session = client.open_channel(kind='session')
session.exec_command(command3)
while True:
    if session.recv_ready():
        stdout_data.append(session.recv(nbytes))
    if session.recv_stderr_ready():
        stderr_data.append(session.recv_stderr(nbytes))
    if session.exit_status_ready():
        break

print 'exit status: ', session.recv_exit_status()
print ''.join(stdout_data)
print ''.join(stderr_data)

session.close()
client.close()
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to set the local environment variable before establishing the connection. You should use `os.environ`, which is a dictionary reflecting the environment.

Comment: OK, how would I implement that please?

Comment: `os.environ['ASPERA_SCP_PASS']` returns the value you entered above in python.

Comment: I am sorry, but i don't understand how I can use this within my code, could you give an example with my code please?

Comment: I've updated the original question.

Comment: these are bash commands, right? shouldn't you separate them with `;` instead of `,`? and shouldn't you set the env variable first?

Comment: Tried those suggestions, still not working.

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
command1 = 'set ASPERA_SCP_PASS={}'.format(os.environ['ASPERA_SCP_PASS'])
```

Comment: I have updated the question, and now I get ‘exit status:  0’, but the command does not run on the remote server.

Comment: Running this above commadn I get raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'ASPERA_SCP_PASS'

Comment: please clarify what you do on the local and what on the remote machine.

Comment: I am running this python script on my local OSX machine, and using this python script I am trying to SSH into a Windows Server machine which is on IP address 10.0.0.1, and run a command line application called ascp.exe. This ascp.exe needs the local environment setting (on the remote Windows Server machine).

Comment: then you can hard-code the password into your code; or is there a reason you write it into the environment variables (which is not good security practice...). and i give up; sorry; no windows experience.

Comment: I dont think there is a way to hard-code the password into my code, unless you can suggest a way?